# Multi Row coulmn in gridview for values with same ID

Tags: c#, gridview, sqlcommand

i have basic knowledge in C# and VisualStudio 
using visual Studio 2012, C# language, Sql server managmnet studio 2012 to create my database

I have Documents related to Some Activities, one Activity can have many Docs,

i have the gridview shown like this :

[Gridview Shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZMQJ.png)

i dont want the id to be repeated
can i make the documents with the same id 
in multi rows ?

[Table in the DataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdEDW.png)

Code to populate GV:

```
  protected void populateTaskActivityDocGv()
    {
        CRUD MyCRUD = new CRUD();
        string mySql = @" SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TaskActivityDoc] ";
        SqlDataReader dr = MyCRUD.getDrPassSql(mySql);
        TaskActivityDocGv.DataSource = dr;
        TaskActivityDocGv.DataBind();
    }
```

Class :

```
public SqlDataReader getDrPassSql(string mySql)
{
    SqlDataReader dr;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@mySql, con);
    con.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    return dr;
    con.Close();
}
```

let me know if i forget to include any needed information

Comment: You forgot to add the code you use to populate the grid.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava done, thanks